# How to stop Hotmail Active View from previewing video links in HTML Newsletters

Tags: html, preview, newsletter, hotmail, activeview

I have created a custom HTML newsletter for a client and it is working correctly in all clients.
In Hotmail, the video link from the newsletter is being previewed at the top of the page by active view.

The youtube link:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dir1TegFGVs" target="_blank" style="color: #0099cc; text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px;">
```

I know that [active view can be deactivated by the user](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/15375/hotmail-how-to-disable-active-view/) , but I'd like to know if it's possible to code the newsletter so that hotmail does not preview video links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried minified URLs like http://youtu.be/dir1TegFGVs or some other types like http://goo.gl/?

Comment: Great! - I used the http://goo.gl service to minify the URL and it now works perfectly. Really appreciate your help Henrik!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could think of a different approach that worked out well.